# what to do when ' repair table ' query won't work in mysql?

Tags: mysql

i got this error : "The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair"

when i tried to repair the table using the query `repair table tbl_college_master`

table is of innodb type, but i dont know y i'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try [mysql repair tool](http://www.mysqlrepair.org) . . . it's a great tool that can repair any type of mysql data or table containing any data. and i am sure that it will definetely repair the table using the query repair table tbl_college_master.

Comment: link is not broken!

Comment: I found a 'mysql repair tool' with 'how to' in [this page](https://www.repairtoolbox.com/mysqlrepair.html). Maybe it's the same... but require a donation.

Answer (score 13):

See [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html)—`REPAIR TABLE` is only applicable to MyISAM, ARCHIVE and CSV storage engines.

With InnoDB you don't need this anyway, as the storage engine can't go into an inconsistent state unlike MyISAM and others.